# Regex remove blank lines, but leave new line

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this regex to remove blank lines:

```
(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+
```

in php:

```
$search = array(
            '@( |\t|\f)+@', // Shorten multiple whitespace sequences
            '@^\s+|\s+$@',  // Trim lines
            '@(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+@'    //Remove blank lines
            );
$replace = array(' ','',"\r\n");
$string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

however I have some problems with this code in particular:
Original:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
iCart.init({
    title: 'Aggiungi',
    cart: 'Carrello',
....
</script>
```

After replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[iCart.init({
title: 'Aggiungi',
cart: 'Carrello',
....
</script>
```

Wha tI'm trying to obtain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
iCart.init({
title: 'Aggiungi',
cart: 'Carrello',
....
</script>
```

I have done some tests with regex101 ([FIDDLE](https://www.regex101.com/r/yT6oJ0/1)) and it gives me back the right result, but I can't achive the same aim on a real enviroment

**EDIT**
Change the find regex (the trim created some problems):

```
$search = array(
                 '@( |\t|\f)+@',    // Shorten multiple whitespace sequences
                 '@^\s+|[ \t]+$@gmi'    //Remove blank lines
                );
$replace = array(' ','');
$string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

But still have got the problem

Comment: What is the problem?  What does it do and what do you want it to do?

Comment: This may be exactly what you want (a lot simpler, so tell me if it works and I'll post an answer with explanation): [`\v$`](https://regex101.com/r/iJ5lN7/1)

Comment: @Sam Is there a way to avoid the space after substitution?

Comment: @Dheed take a look at my answer. It works for your example.

Comment: @Sam I have tried it, but the result doesn't change, maybe I should find the problem somewhere else

Comment: As far as I can tell, [my solution](http://ideone.com/0OJpwG) aligns perfectly with your intended output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you want: [`^\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/iJ5lN7/2)

---

**Use:**

```
$string = preg_replace('/^\s+/m', '', $string);
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `^` anchors to the beginning of a new line with the `m` multi-line modifier
- `\s+` finds 1+ whitespace (`[\r\n\t\f ]`) character; this could be an entire blank line or just preceding indents